# Store mutiple values for same entity and attribute in EAV

Tags: eav

Beginner to eav model,I am having an entity table,attribute table and value table.

Entity Table

```
|entity_id|entity_name|
```

Attribute table

```
|attribute_id|attribute_name|
```

value table:

```
|entity_id|attribute_id|value|
```

For same entity_id and attribute_id I have multiple values.

e.g

| entity_id | attribute_id | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1.2 |
| 1 | 1 | 1.3 |

this causes duplicates in eav table.how to populate the data

Comment: Hi, welcome to dba.se! `EAV` - it's an [anti-pattern](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A34007+eav)! Check out [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A34007+eav), and [this](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/t-sql-programming-sql-server/avoiding-the-eav-of-destruction/). There is only one major commercial system that uses it (Magento) and that's for a very particular use case - fashion (and, even then, I think they shouldn't have used EAV - personal opinion). As a **basic first principle** of db design - every entity should be a table of its own!

Comment: If you want to have multiple values either extend the key or use a collection of some kind (for example array) for value. EAV will lead you into all kinds of trouble and is nost of the time the wrong way to go. Concider rethinking your design, cry once now or cry forever after.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Comment: EAV does not require attribute per entity uniqueness. But general logic needs in priority ordering which must be provided.

Comment: @akina can you please elaborate priority ordering

Comment: @Atchaya - consider using PostgreSQL and JSONB (or equivalent on your system of choice).